# Remove embedded images in HTML email using On-send feature

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

To remove embedded images in HTML email, use the `removeAttachmentAsync()` method (in Mailbox API).
The `removeAttachmentAsync()` method completes successfully, but behaves differently as follows:

- Outlook on the web (OWA):

  - The sent e-mail has no embedded images. This works as I expected.
- Outlook on Windows:

  - The sent e-mail still has embedded images.

What is the correct way to remove embedded images in Outlook for Windows?

**First code:**

```js
const test = async (event) => {
  let timeout = null;
  const item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
  item.getAttachmentsAsync((result) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < result.value.length; i++) {
      item.removeAttachmentAsync(result.value[i].id, (result2) => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          event.completed({ allowEvent: true });
        }, 500);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

---

**Update:**

I rewrote the code using the `setAsync()` method. The behavior has changed:

- Outlook on Windows:

  - The sent e-mail has embedded blank images.

**Edited code:**

```js
const test = async (event) => {
  let timeout = null;
  const item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
  item.getAttachmentsAsync((result) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < result.value.length; i++) {
      item.removeAttachmentAsync(result.value[i].id, (result2) => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, (result3) => {
            item.body.setAsync(result3.value, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html }, () => {
              event.completed({ allowEvent: true });
            });
          });
        }, 500);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: After calling `removeAttachmentAsync()`, you need to get rid of the reference to the image in the body by calling `body.setAsync()` documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=outlook-js-preview#setasync-data--callback-

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Now the image disappears by using the edited code.
Should I remove IMG tag manually in order to do the same as OWA?

Comment: Yes, removing the `IMG` tag is part of getting rid of the reference to the image in the body.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I tried various things based on the information you gave me.
As a result, I noticed that resizing the image would cause `v:imagedata` tags to be present in the mail, and if I removed the `IMG` tag but the `v:imagedata` tag remained, the `IMG` tag would be generated.
So I removed the `v:imagedata` tag and its related tags, it seems to be worked fine.
Also, I removed the `IMG` tag directly without using the `removeAttachmentAsync()` method, which provided a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

The code that solved the question:

```js
const removeImagesFromBody = (event) => {
  const item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
  const type = Office.CoercionType.Html;
  item.body.getAsync(type, (result) => {
    let body = result.value;

    let match;
    const regex1 = new RegExp('v:shapes="([^"]+)"', 'gi');
    while ((match = regex1.exec(result.value)) !== null) {
      const regex2 = new RegExp(`<v:shape id="${match[1]}"[^]*?</v:shape>`, 'gi');
      body = body.replace(regex2, '');
    }

    body = body.replace(/<img [^>]*>/gi, '');
    item.body.setAsync(body, { coercionType: type }, () => {
      event.completed({ allowEvent: true });
    });
  });
}
```